# POSIX getopts refuses to acknowledge numeric $OPTARG value

Tags: posix, numeric, arguments, getopts

I'm using getopts to parse options for a custom script running under bash.

The code to achieve this is very standard:

```
while getopts :s: opt; do
  case $opt in
    s)
      echo "\$OPTARG is $OPTARG"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

However $OPTARG is empty for a parameter I've specified with a numeric argument:

```
myscript.sh -s 012345 # => [ $OPTARG = "" ]
```

The issue can be resolved by wrapping the argument in quotes. This is ugly for a numeric argument though.

```
myscript.sh -s "012345" #  => [ $OPTARG = "012345" ]
```

Is there a more elegant solution than this?

**UPDATE**

It turns out my actual code had a ':' missing, so the parameter wasn't expecting an argument. I don't know why the string value printed out what was expected, but the numeric argument works now I've specified that the parameter takes an arg.

Comment: You should show your code and specify exactly which shell you're using.

Comment: Done, thanks for the wise suggestion.

Comment: It works for me, output: `$OPTARG is 012345`. What version of Bash? Do you have a shebang in your script (it's not shown in your code)?

Comment: Ack I've just realised why it wasn't working, post updated. Thanks for testing for me Dennis, much appreciated!

Comment: You can post your finding as an answer then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the actual code in use had a ':' missing, so the parameter wasn't expecting an argument. Changing from `getopts :s` to `get opts :s:` solved the issue. Note that the leading colon has a different meaning - its inclusion disables error output for getopts, so unrecognized options will not be reported.